# Specify number of map points display on maps in Microsoft PowerBi

Tags: powerbi

I am working with Longitude-Latitude values using the default powerBi map visualization. I want to be able to specify a certain distance and also be able to specify how many map points will be displayed within that radius. For example I would like maps to plot 500 or less lat-long points within any 1 mile radius in the US. Just to be clear, maps should plot all map points within the US that are quantity 500 or less in any 1 mile radius.
Can anyone help me to solve this in PowerBi or is there any other visualization tool in powerBi that can help me to do this?

Comment: Please try something first and then post your question with codes.

Comment: So this is exactly my situation; I have plotted over a 500,000 lat-long points all across the united states and I want maps to show me where the points are mostly clustered or concentrated at within a small area (rectangular or otherwise, eg within any 50meters radius).